# Error permitted_uri_chars in CodeIgniter

Tags: php

i have make an page controller and i can generate the pages with tinymce

the problem is when the page name is arabic like this

Example:http://domain/solarBlog/blog/category/السلمي

showing error

> **The URI you submitted has disallowed characters**

is there any way to make the uri allowing the arabic characters ?

also im using the default

```
$config[‘permitted_uri_chars’] = ‘a-z 0-9~%.:_\-’;
```

> **Please note that I used version 2.1.0**

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter does not allows submitting some characters to be passed. But in case of Non latin languages, the data will be encoded and passed which will generate some non permitted characters in the encoded string. So the solution is just remove some characters like % in the $config['permitted_uri_chars'] which will be used mostly while encoding the URL. But it is not recommended as per the codeigniter documentation. For more information click [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_140.html).

Comment: Dear Udhay, I would like to support the Arabic language in `permitted_uri_chars`.

Comment: You can add the support for any language by using the language library and helper.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/language_helper.html

But for the problem you have mentioned above, you have to remove some characters in `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` to make it work.

Comment: By setting $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_+&-';

Comment: Unfortunately, I have printed this `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters`.

Comment: First try removing % if it is not working then set `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = "";`

Comment: I apologize did not work - `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = "";` show to me `Disallowed Key Characters.`